# Lebesgue measure of a set

Tags: measure-theory

Let *m* the n-dimensional Lebesgue measure on $R^n$.By definition of product measure, on each borelian set E

$m(E)=\inf \left(\sum_{j=1}^\infty m(R_j),\:\: E\subseteq \bigcup R_j , \:\:R_j \text{ rectangles}\right)$

It is also true that lebesgue measures are regular, so
$m(E)=\inf \left(m(U), E\subseteq U, \: U \text{ open set} \right)$.

Can I say that also holds
$m(E)=\inf \left(\sum_{j=1}^\infty m(B_j),\:\: E\subseteq \bigcup B_j , \:\:B_j \text{ balls}\right)$ or not?

Comment: Yes, this is Vitali's covering theorem.


Comment: Typo? Did you really mean for the upper bound of each summation to be n?

Comment: In fact, the upper bounds in sums should be removed. You need countable coverings in both cases, finite ones are not enough.


Comment: Yes, typo, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It follows from Vitali's covering theorem but not in an entirely trivial
fashion. We can reduce to the case where $E$ is open of finite measure.
The set of all open balls contained in $E$ is then a Vitali cover. By Vitali's
covering theorem there is a sequence of disjoint balls $(B_n)$
whose union is a subset $U$ of $E$ with the same measure as $E$.
Thus $F=E-U$ is a set of Lebesgue measure zero.

Let $\epsilon>0$. There is a sequence of open cubes covering $F$
with total measure $<\epsilon$. Circumscribe these with balls
and we get a sequence of open balls covering $F$ with total measure $< c_n\epsilon$
where $c_n>0$. Interweaving this sequence with the $(B_n)$ we get
a sequence of balls covering $E$ of total measure $< m(E)+c_n\epsilon$.